Make ag-grid search for formatted value in "quick filter"
I'm trying to implement a grid with a free text search box using the quick filter feature in AgGrid.
I found that it doesn't search for the formtted value, only for the real value.
I guess it could be accomplished with the getQuickFilterText on the column def, but this seems like a common feature I whould assume is already supported. Is there a useValueFormatterForQuickFilter option, like we have a useValueFormatterForExport option?
Thanks
I've tried using the getQuickFilterText to work arround it, but this requires adding this to each column def, which is quite annoying.

This is supported using the getQuickFilterText as mentioned in the docs you can use this to format string values specifically for searching. If you are using the same formatting for all of your columns you could add this to the default column def.
Currently there is no useValueFormatter... function for this.
